# How to plot ranges of two variables with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with four variables as follows:

```
my_matrix <- matrix (c("D1",5,25, 100,200,
           "D2",6,30,150,250,
           "D3",7,32,180,300), nrow =3, byrow = T)
my_matrix <- as.data.frame(my_matrix)
names(my_matrix) <- c("Layer","Tmin", "Tmax", "Pmin", "Pmax")
my_matrix$Tmin <- as.numeric(as.character(my_matrix$Tmin)) 
my_matrix$Tmax <- as.numeric(as.character(my_matrix$Tmax)) 
my_matrix$Pmin <- as.numeric(as.character(my_matrix$Pmin)) 
my_matrix$Pmax <- as.numeric(as.character(my_matrix$Pmax))
```

I plotted the ranges of Pmin and Pmax for Layer variable as follow:

```
ggplot(my_matrix, aes(Layer))+
 geom_linerange(aes(ymin= Pmin,ymax= Pmax),linetype=1,color="red")+
 geom_point(aes(y=Pmin),size=3,color="blue")+
 geom_point(aes(y=Pmax),size=3,color="blue")
```

[image]

I also plotted ranges for Tmin and Tmax for Layer variable:

```
ggplot(my_matrix, aes(y= Layer))+
 geom_linerange(aes(xmin = Tmin, xmax = Tmax),linetype=1,color="red" )+
 geom_point(aes(x=Tmin),size=3,color="blue")+
 geom_point(aes(x=Tmax),size=3,color="blue")
```

[image]

I want to combine these two plots into one plot where x-axis shows the ranges of Tmin and Tmax, while y-axis shows the ranges of Pmin and Pmax for Layer variable. There should be 3 plus sign on the plot for D1,D2,and D3 at the end. How can I plot this?

Comment: You could try `geom_errorbar` and define ymin ...

Comment: @Paul It gives error. It requires xmin and xmax.